# Windows 11, running in qemu (ubuntu host) can't see Windows domain controller on VPN (openfortivpn)

Tags: linux, windows, vpn, qemu

Details:

- Windows 11 Pro (guest)
- Ubuntu 22.04 (host)
- qemu 6.2 (as provided by Ubuntu repos)
- openfortivpn 1.17.1

I'm WFH, primarily in Linux, and when I need work resources I start openfortivpn to access them. In Linux this works fine. Very rarely I need to use Windows, and right now that means rebooting into my W11Pro partition, running FortiVPN, doing some work and then booting back to Linux. To alleviate some of this hassle I created a qemu/kvm VM with W11Pro installed. Windows works well, but I need it to join the domain. I've tried starting openfortivpn first, then launching the VM, but it always reports that it can't find the domain controller. I can ping the DC's IP address from the linux cli. The virtual network interface has the "network source" set to "Virtual network 'default' : NAT", and in Windows I have overridden the DNS servers so that the work DNS server is the first one (8.8.8.8 is the second).

One thing I've noticed about our openfortivpn config that seems to be different from other VPNs is that it doesn't create a new default route, which is what I see happening with expressvpn on my home PC. Instead, openfortivpn creates a LOT of new rules in the routing table for the the different work machines. One of them is specifically for the IP of the domain controller.

I ran a test where I inspected the state of openfortivpn's interface (ppp0) with `ifconfig ppp0` and noted the packets sent and received, then tried to connect to the domain, and inspected the interface again. There was no change in the number of packets. This leads me to believe that there is probably something in the firewalling rules that is preventing the packets from moving from the VM's interface to the VPN's.

I could run the FortiVPN client within the VM and that would likely solve my immediate problem, but I would really prefer to understand why what I'm doing now is not working.

Comment: I'm guessing it's `Virtual network 'default' : NAT` that is likely the issue. That extra NAT may be incompatible with how FortiVPN works - try `bridge` - though you'll need to configure a bridge on the host of course